# Difference between matplotlib's plot() and pandas plot()?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

What is the difference between `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()` and `pandas.DataFrame.plot()`?

We can plot using both but what is the measure difference between both?

How can i draw bar chart and group by some categorical variable?

Answer (score 5):

Matplotlib's pyplot is the library that Pandas use in their plot function. Pandas' plot is only a convenient shortcut. 
For the bar chart question: I would suggest using Seaborn's [barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html), using the desired category as *hue*.
If you wish to only use Pandas, then maybe something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 1), columns=['col_name'])
df['category'] = df.col_name>0.5

print(df)

   col_name  category
0  0.053908     False
1  0.136295     False
2  0.325790     False
3  0.362942     False
4  0.919924      True
5  0.406884     False
6  0.433959     False
7  0.725699      True
8  0.582537      True
9  0.608040      True

df.groupby('category').count().plot(kind='bar', legend=False)
```

[image]