# what's the difference between plt.plot(), object.plot()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made a list

```
> Book_of_Death_Count

1.0    49
2.0    73
3.0    97
4.0    27
5.0    61
Name: Book of Death, dtype: int64*
```

When I type

```
a = Book_of_Death_Count.plot(),
b = plt.plot(Book_of_Death_Count)
```

The result of the two is the same, but:

- `a.set_xticks(np.arange(1,6))` works;
- `b.set_xticks(np.arange(1,6))` doesn't work.

What's the difference of these two code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between matplotlib's plot() and pandas plot()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51374539/difference-between-matplotlibs-plot-and-pandas-plot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your "list" is a [pandas DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html) object. When you call `Book_of_Death_Count.plot()` you are using the function [DataFrame.plot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html?highlight=plot#pandas.DataFrame.plot), which returns (in most cases) an Axes object. Therefore `a` is of Type `Axes` and you can use it to access [all the methods](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html) of that class.

When you use [`plt.plot()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html?highlight=plot#matplotlib.pyplot.plot), the return values is a list of [`Line2D` objects](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D). If you need to access the Axes object (for instance to modify the ticks), use [`a = plt.gca()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gca.html?highlight=gca#matplotlib.pyplot.gca).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `a` is a pandas Series: whenever you call [`my_pandas_series.plot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html), the return value is an [`Axes` instance](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html), an object which represents you plot region as a whole. This object has a `set_xticks` method for... well, setting the position of the x ticks in the plot.

On the other hand, calling [`plt.plot()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) returns a list of [`Line2D` objects](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D). Neither the list nor the `Line2D` objects inside it contains a `set_xticks` method.