# What is the difference between plt.plot() and ax.plot()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this code creates a figure containing all of the objects and axes with ticks containing the plot elements:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
```

Then, this code creates an `ndarray` and plots it in the `ax` object region:

```
x = np.linspace(start=0, stop=10)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
```

But this code produces exactly the same result:

```
x = np.linspace(start=0, stop=10)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))
```

I see the latter more often, but I wonder why it's preferred more. Do they do the same thing, or are they different, and if so, what are the differences and why is one preferred?

Also, I looked at this post [what's the difference between plt.plot(), object.plot()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60227407/whats-the-difference-between-plt-plot-object-plot), and it doesn't answer the question, because I'm not asking about a `DataFrame`.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/index.html#the-pyplot-api

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#working-with-multiple-figures-and-axes . `pyplot` *uses the current axes.